# db2 Error sqlcode: -1224

Tags: db2, sqlcode

Has anyone seen this type pf error msg before. I cannot find documentation on sql code -1224?

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:

SQLCA Information

sqlcaid : SQLCA     sqlcabc: 136   sqlcode: -1224   sqlerrml: 0
 sqlerrmc: 
 sqlerrp : SQLJRERM
 sqlerrd : (1) -2143879059      (2) 0                (3) 0
           (4) 0                (5) 0                (6) 0
 sqlwarn : (1)      (2)      (3)      (4)        (5)       (6)
           (7)      (8)      (9)      (10)       (11)
 sqlstate: 55032

Answer (score 0):

Always try to check IBM infocenter with such errors:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql01224n.html

Short comment from my side:

A reboot could fix your problem, if you can in your environment.
If it's a production server, I suggest a db2stop and afterwards a db2start , this could also help

Normally, -1224 is a trap which comes from memory corruption.

If you run the function unfenced, try to switch to fenced.
Also, take a look at your trap files.

Also, this can happen if you have an invalid JVM level. Make sure you use a supported jdk level => move to the latest version